# Python and cplex configuration

Tags: python, python-2.7, cplex

I am new to Cplex and i am trying to setup Cplex 12.6 with python but the build fails: i have a Python 2.7 and i use the following command in terminal and this the  [response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aTwWR.png).

When i try to make sure i m using python 2.7 version the terminal can only show me the following version:

```
Python 2.7.13 |Anaconda 4.3.0 (64-bit)| (default, Dec 19 2016, 13:29:36)[MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Anaconda is brought to you by Continuum Analytics.
```

Is this why the build fails? If anyone has an idea please share it with me.

Comment: Instead of linking to a screenshot for the response, please put the text here (as you did for the Anaconda version).  This makes it easier for people to help you.

Comment: Okey rkersh i've solved the problem i ve installed cplex using a command provided by the anaconda website

Comment: Are you running `setup.py install` under regular user or admin? Did you try `python setup.py install` as well?

Comment: @Strix: Please post your solution as an [answer to your own question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).